# Is it possible to stream XBMC video plugins over UPnP?

Tags: xbox360, kodi, upnp

Ideally I'd like to be able to stream video from XBMC plugins to an XBOX 360.  I've read UPnP makes it possible to share media, but haven't seen anywhere that indicates the possibility of sharing video that's presently being streamed from the Internet.

In other words, say there's the "streaming TV" plugin for XBMC streaming a show from the PBS website.  This would normally display on the XBMC's display as it's streaming.  Is it possible to use UPnP to share the video with another UPnP device? (the XBOX 360 in my case)

Answer (score 2):

*horatio*
Giving a usage example would be nice. For example, Flicks is a plugin that allows to watch Netflix videos on XBMC. How to add Flicks to XBMC Video Library so that Netflix video can be streamed via XBMC UpNP server to a TV or media player - a step by step guide? When browsing video sources to add to XBMC Library, which category Flicks fits? Of course such advice mandates trying yourself and succeeding (watching Netflix on TV via UpNP from XBMC).

One solution: [XBMC.MyLibrary - Scan any source to the library](http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=98210). This package helps to scan into XBMC Library Netflix, Hulu, and other internet video sources added via plugins, making them accessible via UPnP to other devices.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use XBMC, but it *can* act as a UPnP server:

> XBMC has (since the 24th of January 2007) a built-in UPnP A/V media server (UPnP-server). Originally added to help share files to other XBMC instances as a UPnP media source, XBMC's UPnP server also enables you to share media with other UPnP-clients on your local network. XBMC's UPnP server can share files that are normally only locally accessible on the Host XBMC device, as well as metadata (summaries, cover art, etc) to supporting clients. **As of XBMC v12, the UPnP server can also share files that are not scanned into the library.**

( http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=UPnP/Server )

Additionally, one can set network media sources such as rss feeds, and it supports other protocols based upon backend plugins.

One potential issue you might have is that the 360 only supports a small subset of encoding formats. In the past I worked around this this using server software such as TVersity which transcoded media files on the fly. If you have the proper backend plugins, you can achieve the same thing.

Comment: It seems to me that this answer doesn't answer my question at all: I'm wanting to know whether or not I can display media on an XBOX 360 that's streaming to XBMC running on a separate PC.  Am I missing something?

Comment: yes, you are. In your scenario, the xbmc is a *server* and the 360 is a *client*. The xbmc can serve video from its library to the 360. One can add internet tv and rss video feeds to the library. If they are in the library, they are servable. On the link I provided, there is information about setting up your library to serve file over upnp. My point about transcoding is important: if the feed is not in a format the 360 supports it will not work, but this is will be a problem of codecs available to the 360, rather than a upnp server problem

Comment: Great Horatio, thanks!  It wasn't clear from your answer that internet TV and video feeds were included (you mentioned RSS feeds).  If you make a minor edit and clarify that this includes video feeds that XBMC is using as a streaming input, superuser will let me change the down vote to an up vote.

Comment: You should hold off on that until you find if it is correct in fact: the wiki may be wrong!